# partials not being rendered express-handlebars node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to use `express-handlebars` and use `partials` but I am getting the following error message

> The partial header could not be found.

My `app.js` code looks like as follows.

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', function  (req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This is all working and the express app is running on localhost:3000.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
|_app.js
|_views_
        |_home.hbs
        |_layouts_
                  |_main.hbs
        |_partials_
                   |_header.hbs
```

**main.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example App</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

**header.hbs**

```
<nav>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

**home.hbs**

```
{{> header}}

<h1>Hey world!</h1>
```

Everything works as expected until I try and introduce `header.hbs` as a partial.

Can anyone see any issue with my code?

Following further investigation I have also tried this, without any success:

```
// Create `ExpressHandlebars` instance with a default layout.
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    // Uses multiple partials dirs, templates in "shared/templates/" are shared
    // with the client-side of the app (see below).
    partialsDir: [
        'views/partials/'
    ]
});

// Register `hbs` as our view engine using its bound `engine()` function.
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was necessary to define the following settings for `express-handlebars` partials to work.

```
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('hbs', handlebars({ extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Here is the complete code:

```
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('hbs', handlebars({ extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.render('home');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing the next line:

```
exphbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
```

Comment: TypeError: exphbs.registerPartials is not a function

Comment: @CreasolDev but I am using `express-handlebars`